Error uploading file: An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutObject operation: None
I have this create function using Boto within the Flask and it has been working for months perfectly, but suddenly it just stopped working, and I can't seem to figure out why.
@posts_blueprint.route('/create_post', methods=['POST'])
def create_post():
    if request.files["image"]:
        file = request.files['image']
        folder_path = os.environ.get('S3_FOLDER')
        file_save = folder_path + file.filename
        print(file.filename)
        try:
            client.upload_fileobj(file, 'pythonpat', file_save)
            make_file_public('pythonpat', file_save)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error uploading file: {e}")

        post = Post(title=request.form['title'], body=request.form['body'],
                    author=request.form['author'], image=file_save, slug=slugify(request.form['title']))

        uploaded_tags = request.form['tags']
        saved_tags = uploaded_tags.split(',')
        for tag_name in saved_tags:
            tag_name = tag_name.strip()
            tag = Tag.query.filter_by(name=tag_name).first()
            if not tag:
                tag = Tag(name=tag_name)
            post.tags.append(tag)

        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()

        return jsonify({
            'status': 200,
            'message': 'Post uploaded successfully'
        }), 200
    return jsonify({
        'status': 400,
        'message': 'Image not attached'
    }), 200

and my error:
Error uploading file: An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutObject operation: None

